# Django | Template | Correct way to iterate over list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a variable named `messages` which contains list of dictionaries that I pass to my template,
which is supposed to itearate over the list and print the value for 
key "html" from each dictionary.

**List of dictionaries**

```
[
 '{"body": "asdada", "html": "sfdsfsfw", "id": "sdfsfsf"}',
 '{"body": "dgdgdg", "html": "sfdsfsfs", "id": "sfsfsdf"}', 
 '{"body": "dgeaeg", "html": "sfdaewaa", "id": "sfwaeaw"}'
]
```

**Sample from Template**

```
{% for message in messages %}
{{ message.html }}
{% endfor %}
```

When my webpage is rendered , this for loop prints nothing.I mean its blank in the webpage that I get as a result in my browser.I was expecting it to print

```
sfdsfsfw
sfdsfsfs
sfdaewaa
```

I tried below, but this gives TemplateSyntaxError

```
{% for message in messages %}
{{ message["html"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Need help to figure out correct way to print out the value for key "html" .
Please help!

Comment: It is not a list of dictionary, but a list of strings. (`'...'`)

Comment: Hi, you are right .Stupid me. Please write this as answer so that I can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not a list of dictionary, but a list of strings.

```
[
 '{"body": "asdada", "html": "sfdsfsfw", "id": "sdfsfsf"}',
 '{"body": "dgdgdg", "html": "sfdsfsfs", "id": "sfsfsdf"}', 
 '{"body": "dgeaeg", "html": "sfdaewaa", "id": "sfwaeaw"}'
]
```

String object does not have `html` attribute / item;